# PHP script not responding after some time

Tags: php

I am executing one php script, if data is less (approx 30K), it will take 3 minutes and display the output.

But if data is huge, then execution time is approx 7-8 minutes, but browser is not showing the output. I checked the script with the logs, script is executing till the last line of the code, but browser is not responding that output.

I tried with the lots of options like increase memmory limit, max execution time, but didn't get the solution.

Kindly look into that.....

Comment: your question is ambiguous. show your code maybe I can help you.

Comment: How did you try to increase those limits? Is it your own server or a account on a shared host? Did you verify the changes with a phpinfo() call?

Comment: Please provide your script, and how you connect to the db, what is ur platform? may your script go into an infinite loop or there are problems in the db connections...

Comment: yes, i have used the set time out to 0. also if used the simple 2 lines code  <?php sleep(5000); echo "test"; ?> it is also not working. browser not showing the output "test" after 5 minutes.

Comment: summary of my question is, how to handle that request in php where browser has to wait longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to output some data to the browser. It the browser has to wait for minutes the browser will think that there is a connection timeout.

If possible you could begin to send the html header and `flush` it to the client.

Comment: if used the simple 2 lines code  <?php sleep(5000); echo "test"; ?> it is also not working. browser not showing the output "test" after 5 minutes. Please let me know where i can use flush in this code.

Comment: <?php
set_time_limit(0);
for( $x=1; $x<=100; $x=$x+1 ) {
echo $x . '<br>';
flush();
sleep(3);
}

?> working on my local wamp server, but not working on server

Comment: Try at first to send more bytes initially. In some conditions are 256bytes needed. Also add after each line a linebreak with `\r\n`. If that not work tell me how is php installed as module or as cgi/fastcgi? Check also if `output_buffering` is set in your `php.ini` it should be `off`.

Comment: @user1138143 did that help you? If yes remember to accept answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
header('Connection: keep-alive');
flush();
```

If you have a loop, you can put this in it at last so it will continue your connection.